# Highlight points with different colors using opengl

Tags: opengl

I have plotted a series of points using  glVertex3f() in certain color. Now, when the user clicks on a point, I need to display related points in a different color, while the other ones remain in old color. Tried using the condition mentioned below but color remains the same, which was set first. Is there a way to plot points in different colors?

```
   if((highlightColor)&&(i==0)){                      
         glColor3f(0,1,0);                    
         glVertex3f(tempx,calcy,0);
   } else{
         glColor3f(0,0,1);       
         glVertex3f(tempx,calcy,0);
   }
```

Initially, all points are blue. Then I set the variable highlightColor to true if I want to highlight some points with a different color and call this method again. Color does not change to green. Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: I am using c++ for this implementation. Please let me know if opengl supports what i am looking for...

Answer (score 1):

If you have depth testing enabled, if the highlighted draw is not first, it might be getting rejected because it would fail the depth test against the z-buffer. It could also be that you aren't clearing the depth buffer? If you dont want to turn depth testing off (e.g. to avoid state switch), then you could shift the z of the highlighted point closer so it passes the depth test.

Also, are you sure that the `if` condition passes at all? if so, as a sanity check, you could draw to slightly shifted/offsetted (x,y) in some empty space just to make sure that it is actually entering that block.

It could simply be that another blue point could drawn on top of it. You will have to post more code to show what you are doing.

Comment: Yes I am sure that it enters the condition block. I have tested this by printing out inside the block. All points are plotted in blue first. Then second call to the function, enters the if loop and color changes to blue and goes back to green in a flash.

Comment: do you mean it changes to green then goes back to blue? This might indicate that it is working but the condition is only true for a very short time (maybe just for 1 frame) in which case you would need to extend the highlight duration so it is noticeable